# Shulchan Aruch UTF-8

Tags: books-generally, shulchan-aruch

There are lots of Shulchan Aruch e-book applications for various different smart phones, but each is tied to the a particular smartphone platform.

Does anybody know where I can find a copy of the complete Shulchan Aruch (by R' Yosef Karo and the REMA) in UTF-8 text format? (Or in XML format with the text in UTF-8, and the XML to denote different sections of the text.)

(I am not looking for the Ba'al HaTanya's Shulchan Aruch.)

Comment: Basically, I'm interested in whatever the source text is for the smartphone applications.

Comment: I'm not sure which smartphone apps you're talking about, but are you sure they have the actual text and didn't just scan it? And/or they typed it up themselves and didn't get it from anywhere online...

Comment: @yydl: The smartphone apps are available at http://www.jewishcontent.org/pda/

Comment: @yydl: There are now Android apps too. They're not available at the above URL. Instead they're at [jewishcontent.org/android](http://www.jewishcontent.org/android/)

Comment: Good question. +1. Have you contacted the jewishcontent.org PDA-app developer(s)? I, too, am curious where they got their Shulchan Aruch text. The Palm version's About box says "text provided by Moshe Davidovici", but doesn't provide an email address.

Answer (score 5):

A Hebrew version is being compiled on the Hebrew WikiSource site:

[http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן ערוך](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A)

Comment: Avi, A belated welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for pointing us to this resource! I'm sorry that I missed the chance to welcome you the first time around, but I do look forward to continuing to see you around the site.

Answer (score 4):

[Orayta](http://code.google.com/p/orayta/) includes machine-readable copies of Orach Chayim and part of Yoreh Deah, as well as many other interesting seforim (all of which are machine readable).

Answer (score 3):

It's not complete but it is UTF-8:

http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch

As it is a wiki, over time more and more is added to it.